# adding single quota in regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is my original regex:

```
$patt .= "([".preg_quote($letter).']+\s*(\s*([^\d\w]|[_]|(&#.+;)|<br\s*[\/]?>)\s*)*)+';
```

In which I want to add option for `'`. I added in this way

```
$patt .= "([".preg_quote($letter).']+\s*(\s*([^\d\w]|[_]|(&#.+;')|<br\s*[\/]?>)\s*)*)+';

$patt .= "([".preg_quote($letter).']+\s*(\s*([^\d\w]|[_]|[']|(&#.+;)|<br\s*[\/]?>)
```

\s*)*)+';

```
$patt .= "([".preg_quote($letter).']+\s*(\s*([^\d\w]|[_]|(')|(&#.+;)|<br\s*[\/]?>)\s*)*)+';
```

Also by enclosing in to `""`, none of them works. All gives regex invalid in that case. What is correct way to add `'` into filtering rule

Comment: Can you write your intended regex without any enclosing string quotes? It is hard to tell where you are trying to end strings and where you want quotation characters in your regex.

Comment: I can't read this... My eyes burn

Comment: @Mike: I have given original regex, do you want anything eles?

Comment: I disabled the syntax highlighting, so it should be a little easier to read now.

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose your regexp in double quotes:

```
$patt .= "([".preg_quote($letter)."]+\s*(\s*([^\d\w]|_|(&#.+;')|<br\s*\/?>)\s*)*)+";
```

By the way, to match the single character `_` or the single character `\/` it is not necessary to make a class out of them.

Comment: nothing in it before concat. In regex101, it looks fine but when I tested in my app, it gives error